# Pandas Finding Index From Values In Column

Tags: python, pandas

In using Python Pandas on a big dataset, how can I find the index based on the value in the column, in the same row?

For example, if I have this dataset...

```
           Column
Item 1     0
Item 2     20
Item 3     34
...
Item 1000  12
```

... and if I have this value 17 in one of the 1000 rows (excluding row 0) in the column, and I want to find out which one of the Item has this value 17 in the column in the same row, how can I do that?

For example, I want to find out what and where is this Item x indexed in the dataset as shown below...

```
           Column
Item x     17
```

... how can I do that with Pandas, using this value 17 as reference?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
df.index[df.Column == 17]
```

If need excluding row 0:

```
df1 = df.iloc[1:]
df1.index[df1.Column == 17]
```

Sample:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Column': {'Item 1': 0, 'Item 2': 20, 'Item 5': 12, 'Item 3': 34, 'Item 7': 17}})
print (df)
       Column
Item 1       0
Item 2      20
Item 3      34
Item 5      12
Item 7      17
```

```
print (df.index[df.Column == 17])
Index(['Item 7'], dtype='object')

print (df.index[df.Column == 17].tolist())
['Item 7']

df1 = df.iloc[1:]
print (df1)
        Column
Item 2      20
Item 3      34
Item 5      12
Item 7      17

print (df1.index[df1.Column == 17].tolist())
['Item 7']
```

Comment: If this column has a name to it, like 'First Pillar', how will the code be? I tried your code with name change to the df like new[new.Column == 17] but it returns error.

Comment: I think you need `print (df[df['First Pillar'] == 17])`

Comment: You can test it with `df = pd.DataFrame({'First Pillar': {'Item 1': 0, 'Item 2': 20, 'Item 5': 12, 'Item 3': 34, 'Item 7': 17}})
print (df)`

Comment: this does not work for floating point column values ://

Answer (score 2):

use `query`

```
df.query('Column == 17')
```

use `index.tolist()` to get the list of items

```
df.query('Column == 17').index.tolist()
```

Answer (score 2):

I tried one of the methods above and it did not work for me. I then put a bit more thought into it and realized I was making it more complicated than it needed to be. Here's the method I am using in my own program to get this functionality:

```
x = 17
df = pandas.DataFrame({'Item':[1,2,3,150],'Column':[0,20,34,17]})
response = df[df['Column'] == x].iloc[0]['Item']

print(response)
```

Output:

```
150
```